# Grub does not open automatically

Tags: grub

I have been using elementary OS for some time now(months). I have it dual-booted with Windows 10. What I did to open elementary OS was to press "esc" while booting, then choose boot options, then ubunty and after that grub would open. Thats how I have been using elementary OS. If I don't this windows 10 will be booted automatically. Someone please help me I want grub to open at automatically when I start my system(laptop) and I can choose windows or Elementary OS then.
I have a HP laptop with specifications:
i-3 6006U
8GB DDR4 ram
1TB Rom

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be changed in Windows, as that OS loves to take control of the boot partition. Fortunately, it’s not too hard to fix.

In Windows:

1. Open “Command Prompt” as administrator
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
   ```
3. Restart the machine to test